# Brain.js return null, NaN values in training

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, neural-network, brain.js

I'm using Brain.js to make Gomoku AI, and even though the size of Input is fixed at 225, it's not trained. (All values are null, training error is only NaN.)

[Picture of trained model .json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNeac.png)

And is it right to put '00' in the process of filling data to flatten Input's size to 225?
The Training Data is written like as follows:

```
[
  {
    input: [
      '00', '00', '00', '00', ... fill '00' in to empty space to fit 225 size
    ],
    output: { '88': 1 } //The winning player's move have 1 value
  },
  {
    input: [
      '88', '00', '00', '00', ... fill '00' in to empty space to fit 225 size
    ],
    output: { '89': 0 } //The losing player's move have 0 value
  },
  {
    input: [
      '88', '89', '00', '00', ... fill '00' in to empty space to fit 225 size
    ],
    output: { '68': 1 }
  }
]
```

How should I fix it to make the train successfully?
[**and Here's my code.**](https://github.com/gkfyddl2662/Brain.Gomoku)

and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question. You mentioned that your training error was NaN, but you're also using a model that's already trained. Do you want to use a pretrained model or train your own model? By using the sample training data, I was able to successfully run net.train() with that data and get an error of 0.02 after 150 iterations